# Overloading assignment operator in polymorphic classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I'm coming from java so please bear with me.  I've read several other articles and can't seem to find an answer.

I've got a base class (Obj) header file shown below.

```
class Obj {
public:
    Obj();
    Obj(int);
    int testInt;
    virtual bool worked();

    Obj & operator = (const Obj & other) {
        if(this != &other) {
            //other.testInt = this->testInt;
            return *this;
        }
    }
};
```

Base class

```
Obj::Obj() {

}

Obj::Obj(int test) {
    this->testInt = test;
}

bool Obj::worked() {
    return false;
}
```

Here's the child class header

```
class Obj1 : public Obj {
public:
    Obj1();
    Obj1(int);
    virtual bool worked();
};
```

Child class

```
#include "Obj1.h"

Obj1::Obj1() {

}

Obj1::Obj1(int a) {
    this->testInt = a / 2;
}

bool Obj1::worked() {
    return true;
}
```

Here's my main class

```
int main() {
    Obj obj = Obj(99);
    Obj1 obj1 = Obj1(45);

    obj = obj1;

    if(obj.worked())
        cout << "good" << obj.testInt << endl;
    else cout << "bad " << obj.testInt  << endl;

    if(obj1.worked()) {
        cout << "1good " << obj1.testInt << endl;
    } else
        cout << "1bad " << obj1.testInt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output when it's ran

```
bad 99
1good 22
```

How do I get it so **obj = obj1;** (found in main above) makes it so that obj.worked() will return true (since that's how obj1's class defines it)?  Essentially how do I get it to behave like it would in java?  I don't need a deep copy, I just want to toss out what obj used to reference and have it point to obj1 (I think thats how it works in java).

Comment: "How do I get it so obj = obj1; (found in main above) changes the type of obj to obj1" Not at all. It's not possible to change the type of an object once it's been created. You probably don't want to use a virtual assignment operator either. Rather, you should maybe read about pointers if you want polymorphism.

Comment: make `worked()` virtual

Comment: Your assignment operator doesn't return anything in the case of self-assignment (`else` is missing). This invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: krsteeve I made worked() virtual and DyP I removed the virtual off of the assignment operator.  Dyp I have been reading and I can't seem to grasp it, hence why I posted a question here.  I see what you mean though, I don't necessarily want the type to change with obj.  I want it to run the worked() bool from obj1.  How do I make that happen?

Comment: You can not change the type of the object. `obj` will always have a type `Obj` and thus will always return `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I'm not very familiar with Java.*

There's a major difference between "variables" in C++ and Java:

```
class X { public: int m = 5; };

X a; // no `= X();` required
X b;

a = b;
a.m = 42;
print(b.m); // this line is pseudo-code
```

In Java, variables may point to different objects. In the example above, after the assignment, `a` and `b` point to the same object. Modifying this object through one will make the modification visible when accessing the object through the other, `print(b.m)` will print `42`.

In C++, "variables" (actually: *names*) always refer to the same object. There are two objects, one named `a` and one named `b`, and the assignment doesn't change that. Per default/convention, assignment in C++ means (deep) copy. `a = b` will be interpreted by most people and in the case of built-in types as *copy the contents of `b` to `a`* (or, more formally, *change `a` such that it will be equal to `b` afterwards, without altering `b`*).

Now it should be clear that you cannot alter which override of `worked` will be called by using the assignment in C++: which override of a virtual function is called is selected based on the type of the object (dynamic type), and you cannot change which object a name (variable) refers to.

---

However, there are pointers in C++, so-called *raw pointers* and *smart pointers*. Pointers are objects themselves that point to other objects of one specific type. `X*` is a raw pointer that points to an object of type `X` <sub>even with polymorphism!</sub> Similarly, `std::shared_ptr<X>` is a smart pointer that points to an object of type `X`.

```
std::shared_ptr<X> pa = std::make_shared<X>();
std::shared_ptr<X> pb = std::make_shared<X>();
```

Every `make_shared` creates an object. So we have four objects in this example: `pa`, `pb`, and the two unnamed objects created via `make_shared`.

For pointers, there are several operators for dealing with the object pointed to. The most important one is the asterisk, which *dereferences* the pointer. `*pa` will give you the object `pa` points to. The `pa->` operator is a shorthand for `(*pa).`, so you can use it to access members of the object pointed to.
The assignment of pointers *does not copy the object pointed to*. After the assigment `pa = pb`, both will point to the *same object*. For smart pointers, that implies cleaning up objects that are not referred to any more:

```
std::shared_ptr<X> pa = std::make_shared<X>();
std::shared_ptr<X> pb = std::make_shared<X>();
// 4 objects exist at this point
pa = pb;
// only 3 objects still exist, the one `pa` formerly pointed to was destroyed
```

---

Polymorphism in C++ now works with either references (not explained here) or pointers. I said earlier that pointers can only point to one specific type of object. The crux is that this object might be part of a bigger object, e.g. via composition. But inheritance in C++ is very similar to composition: all the members of a base class become part of the *base class subobject* of a derived class' object:

```
std::shared_ptr<Obj1> pobj1 = std::make_shared<Obj1>();
std::shared_ptr<Obj> pobj = pobj1;
```

Here, `pobj` points to the *`Obj` base class subobject* within the object `*pobj1` (i.e. within the object `pobj1` points to).

Polymorphism now works via virtual functions. Those have a special rule for which function is actually called. The expression `*pobj` gives us the object which `pobj` points to, and it is of type `Obj`. But in this example, it is only a *base class subobject*, i.e. the object we originally created is of a type derived from `Obj`. For these cases, we differentiate between the *static* and the *dynamic type* of an expression:

- The static type of `*pobj` is always `Obj` - generally, for an object `p`, whose type is *pointer to `some_type`*, the static type of `*p` is just `some_type`, removing one level of indirection / one *pointer to*.
- The dynamic type of `*pobj` depends on which object `pobj` currently points to, and therefore generally is not known at compile-time. If the object is a *base class subobject*, we use the *derived class object* which it is part of, and recurse until the object we have is not a *base class subobject* any more. The type of the object we end up with is the dynamic type of the expression. In the example above, `pobj` points to the *`Obj` base class subobject* of `*pobj1`. The object `*pobj1` itself is not a *base class subobject* here, therefore the dynamic type of `*pobj` is `Obj1`.

This dynamic type is now used to select which virtual function override is called. In the case `pobj->worked()`, where the dynamic type of `*pobj` is `Obj1`, the override selected is `Obj1::worked`, which will return true.

N.B. As [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) pointed out, the dynamic type does not depend on composition. It is only about inheritance.

Comment: Good, except that it suggests that virtual calls work with composition.  They don't; an inheritance hierarchy is required for virtual dispatch.  (There are workarounds, but this is what the language provides)

Comment: @BenVoigt Tried to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was VERY helpful.  Now I've just gotta do some reading on smart pointers.

Answer (score -1):

In C++, your objects are values not references as in java. The assignment (obj = obj1) will reference to the Obj part of Obj1. In C++ you have to use pointer or reference.

- Pointer

  ```
  Obj* obj = new Obj(99);
  Obj1* obj1 = new Obj1(45);
  delete obj;// you have to free the memory manually as there's no GC in C++
  obj = obj1;
  obj->Worked();// the worked will be true here
  delete obj1; // manually delete it
  ```

  and if you want to delete obj1 via obj (delete obj instead of delete obj1), you have to change the Obj's destructor to be virtual, otherwise the destructor of Obj1 won't be called. Damn, this is C++, enjoy it.
- reference

  ```
  Obj obj = Obj(99);
  Obj1 obj1 = Obj1(45);
  Obj& obj2 = obj1;
  obj2.Worked() // should be true
  ```

  In this case, unlike the pointer, you don't have to delete the objects as they are on stack (not created by 'new'). But you cannot create an array of Obj& (e.g. vector)

Comment: I didn't downvote, because you're right that a pointer should be used.  But gee, manual deletion?  That's like 15 year old C++.  We do have smart pointers.